Powershell command to Save As another extension for an application
Scenario :
MSFT has a software called Power BI desktop in which one can build reports and save the file in 3 different extensions.

Use case:
In case if I have a file with PBIX extension, to convert it into PBIP extension; I have to open the PBIX file via the PBI desktop app and then Save As and then PBIP.
I am able to Open the PBIX file via the below powershell command :
Start-Process -FilePath $PowerBIFilePath

Is there any Powershell command via which I can now save as PBIP ?

With Start-Process the file is simply opened in its assigned program (Power BI Desktop). I don't think you can perform actions in that process from PowerShell other than getting info about the process (window handle, process thread, runtime, etc.) or stopping it.
According to Microsoft's own documentation, programmatically converting PBIX to PBIP is not supported:

Question: Can I convert PBIX into PBIP and vice-versa programmatically?
Answer: No. You can only convert a PBIX into a PBIP and vice-versa using Power BI Desktop's File > Save as.

